# Laravel 5 Class extend

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner to L5. I read the documentation about extending classes but **i didn't find any information about where to put the file in which i extend the class.
**I have to extend Str.php class**. I have read that in L4 it had to be done by putting that file under App/folder but **i didn't find that folder in L5**.
So please can you tell me how can i do that?
This is the information i have now:

1. First, you must find where the class file is. We will be extending the Str class, which is under vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support. Note that you can also find this class under the aliases key in app/config/ app.php.
2. Now create a new folder called lib under app/folder. This folder will hold our class extensions. Because the Str class is grouped under the folder Support, it is suggested that you create a new folder named Support under lib too.
3. Now create a new file named Str.php under app/lib/Support, which you've just created:

But this is for L4

Answer (score 0):

That's more of a general PHP question and there are two parts: 1) How to extend a class and 2) where to put files.

1) Extending classes isn't something Laravel or anyone else provides. That's right there in the language:

```php
class A {}

class B extends A {}
```

As long as class `A` exists and is available, then class `B` can extend from it.

2) Where the files are is also important here. If you're defining class `B` and want to extend class `A`, the php runtime needs to know where to find `A`. Usually class `A` isn't defined in the same file as class `B`.

There are many ways to do this. You could [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) class `A` when you define class `B`. That would look something like:

*a.php*

```
class A {}
```

*b.php*

```
require "a.php";

class B extends A {}
```

Now with a lot of files like in the Laravel framework or any worthy library, you're going to have a lot of files to include and have to keep track of how to include those files. That's no fun. So, instead of doing that, PHP has provided a way to *autoload* the classes. That is, if you define classes in a predictable way, PHP can figure out what classes you're talking about without you having to use `require` or `include` statements.

There are also many ways of autoloading php files. In Laravel (and many, many other projects), the [composer autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) is used.

This means that files have to be placed in a pre-defined way in order for the composer autoloader to find them. By reading about the composer autoloader and then digging into the code to see how Laravel's classes are autoloaded, you'll be able to figure out how that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the intricate detail of Peter's answer, I figured I'd write something much more concrete: it doesn't matter.

If you check composer.json, you'll see that we are autoloading everything that is placed inside the `app` directory anyway. Hence, the choice is really yours. All that matters is that you maintain a sensible and readable structure. For example, you could place it in `app/Lib`, and namespace all your classes `App\Lib` (if `App` is your base namespace of course, which can be changed with `php artisan app:name`). Of course, you could also have a folder like `Helpers/Lib` for your extended classes, and keep some form of `helpers.php` with global helper functions in `Helpers`.

Why would you do this? Well, you might want to have an easy way to call your new `Str`functions, so instead of having to do `Str::yourNewMethod($argument)` everywhere, you could add a helper function `yourMethod($argument)` to easier call the function (if you intend to use it extensively).

One thing you have to remember though, as mentioned by Peter, is that the class you are extending won't automagically be found. It will, however, be autoloaded. Hence, to reference it you have to remember to namespace it, such as in the example below.

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers\Lib

Class Str extends \Illuminate\Support\Str {}
```

Also remember to namespace correctly when you call your own class.